# What is a good "WSMan" Client for macOS

Tags: macos

I'am looking for a WSMan Client so I can control intel amt settings.

I will like a client in HomeBrew or MacPorts. It is too hard to build OpenWSMan myself.

I can't find anything on Google.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know what purposes you looking for WSMan Client, but try these two options:

- https://github.com/gomesjj/MeshCommander. -- Native MacOS MeshCommander Application with WSMan possibilities

Comment: That's two answers.  Please post them separately so they may be voted upon and accepted separately.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

or

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/meshcommander -- Web-based (node.js) MeshCommander that you can access through the browser